# java:set the focus to textfield when form load

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a jTextfield. I want to set  focus on this when the form is loaded. How can I do this? I am using Netbeans. I use `requestFocus()` but it is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the focus to a text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640138/setting-the-focus-to-a-text-field)

Comment: I test this answer and it is working for me :) [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640227/3675925](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640227/3675925)

Answer (score 3):

This link might be helpful for you: [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

I would suggest that you use requestFocusInWindow() instead of requestFocus() to achieve the desired functionality.

The reason: (from the same link)

> These methods are now deprecated. Another method, requestFocus, is discouraged because it tries to give the focus to the component's window, which is not always possible. As of JDK 1.4, you should instead use the requestFocusInWindow method, which does not attempt to make the component's window focused. The method returns a boolean value indicating whether the method succeeded.

This would be a crude example, but I think you can use this to get started:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    JTextField textField;

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        textField = new JTextField();

        button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));

        this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        getContentPane().add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        getContentPane().add(button2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //This will set focus on the text field
        textField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**LATEST EDIT : FOR NETBEANS**

CODE USED :

```
package focusexample;

public class FocusExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public FocusExample() {
        initComponents();
        jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1))
                .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2))
                .addContainerGap(98, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(95, 95, 95)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(104, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FocusExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FocusExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FocusExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FocusExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new FocusExample().setVisible(true);                
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: I'm writting the Jtextfield.requestFocusInWindow() below the initComponents() but it not work

Comment: @Jayashri - Can you please post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) for us to better understand your problem?

Comment: public class focus {  initComponents();                                    JTextfield1.requestFocusInWindow(); }

Comment: @Jayashri : Try to add `textFieldObjectrequestFocusInWindow()` after you write `frameObject.setVisible(true);`, i.e. after the Parent Window is visible.

Comment: @nlcE cOw Im trying this but it gives me error as:cannot find symbol ..also trying this.requestFocusInWindow(); It also gives error

Comment: please note that I'm uses netbeans

Comment: Here is one more [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227671/how-to-create-formatted-text-to-show-in-a-java-swing-component-jtextpane-jedit/11229328#11229328)

Comment: @Sujay I'm uses netbeans initComponents() is built in method so how can I do this?

Comment: @Jayashri - you know, you really don't have to write this in initComponent() :D....understand the flow and I think you'll get it!

Small hint: In my case, I could've written it in the constructor itself, right after calling initComponents()

Comment: @nlcE cOw  pls tell me this example in netbeans my project is on deadline pls

Comment: @Sujay I'm writting this method in the constuctor,also trying in the main methos all the possible depends on my project flow bit it cant run

Comment: Feel free to revert back to previous state, if you feel this edit is not worth it. @Jayashri : Here is what I did in my NetBeans and it's working

Comment: @Jayashri : Please check, I had added the whole Project here [FocusExample](https://github.com/gagan119/codingdreams/tree/examples/FocusExample)

Answer (score 0):

I used the textfield.requestFocusInWindow(); line given above, in a GUI that contains a number of form elements (several of which are textfields). It works great. Just replace "textfield" with whatever name you have given the element in question. In my case it's repId. So I use     repID.requestFocusInWindow(); and put the line at the bottom of my ENTER button handler. Now, when a user types data into the form fields and presses ENTER, focus returns to the first textfield: "repID". Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also of note, make sure you place the `requestFocusInWindow()` method after the `pack()` method.  When I was placing the `requestFocusInWindow()` method before the `pack()` method, it didn't work.  I placed the `requestFocusInWindow()` method  after the `pack()` method and it worked.  Little things like that just make life so much easier for us n00bs.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will help you:

```
        JTextField inputText = new JTextField(20);

        frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            inputText.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });
```